# Discord Music Bot "connection" not defined (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I keep getting the error that connection is not defined in my code where is says "const dispatcher = serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);"

```
function play(guild, song) { 
  const queue = new Map()
  const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
  if (!song) {
    serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
    queue.delete(guild.id);
    return;
  }
  const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
    .play(ytdl(song.url))
    .on("finish", () => {
      serverQueue.songs.shift();
      play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
    })
    .on("error", error => console.error(error));
  dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
  serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
}
```

I have tried adding the line "const connection = message.member.voice.channel();" but it says that message is not defined and then when I define message and then member it says the other words are not defined either.

Comment: It is defined in a different part of my code

Comment: then pass message to the function, if you need it.